# Database CREATE TABLE for 2 similar tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, create-table

I have the following information in 2 *.CSV files. There are many more rows but I have included a small set here as an example.

`file_id    descrip Date            file_heat_value_1
1           ABC     2015-02-11      1.02500
1           ABC     2014-11-19      0.85500
1           ABC     2014-05-22      17.20
2           DEF     2014-08-20      1.3700
2           DEF     2014-05-21      15.5500
2           DEF     2013-04-07      77.800
3           XYZ     2012-02-12      0.14400
3           XYZ     2013-02-12      0.97600`

`file_id descrip    Date            file_heat_value_2
1        ABC        2014-12-01      42.01
1        ABC        2013-04-02      11389.90
2        DEF        2014-12-03      0.87
2        DEF        2014-12-04      55.36
2        DEF        2014-07-04      143.29
3        XYZ        2012-11-05      77.90.02
3        XYZ        2013-07-08      34344.91`

I need to add these 2 *.CSV files as tables in a MySQL database. I am not sure if I need 2 tables or one table in the database.

I cannot combine the *.CSV files together because the dates do not match. I will be using MySQL Workbench to load the *.CSV files into the 2 tables.

What I would like to do is this:

1. **Create a database:**

`CREATE schema temperat_monitor`

2. **Create 2 tables**
3. **Run the following query:**

`SELECT
MAX(file_heat_value_1) AS HOT_Temperature,
MIN(file_heat_value_1) AS Cold_Temperature,
MAX(file_heat_value_2) AS HOT_Indoor_Temperature
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.file_id = table_2.file_id`

What would be the best way for me to create the 2 tables in MySQL?

EDIT: My attempt at using the MySQL Workbench File import wizard (6.3.1) is shown in the screenshot below.[image: Image here]. I have created a database and chosen to USE it. But this error comes up. Could you please let me know why this is appearing?

Comment: Can you give the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.3.1 beta a try? It includes an enhanced CSV/JSON import/export feature that should ease your task. It will also create tables for you.

Comment: Hey, this definitely an exciting prospect. If I were to try Workbench 6.3.1 beta, would I then be able to somehow upgrade it to Workbench Release Candidate and then to Workbench stable? Or would I need to uninstall the beta version when the stable version is released? I would strongly prefer the upgrade route than having to uninstall/re-install. If that can be done, then I would definitely give this a go. Also, are there instructions for how to upload multiple *.CSV files to an empty database, in the 6.3.1 beta version?

Comment: No worries about upgrading. It's just a normal installation, like any other, replacing the existing app. You can have 6.2.5 and 6.3.1 installed in parallel (btw. 6.3.1 is now available for download). For multiple CSV files: no, this not yet supported. But the wizard keeps the last settings so you can start it with only a few clicks again, pick the next file and just run the import.

Comment: Ok, I am interested in trying this. I will start looking into this.It may take a bit of fighting though as I have never used Workbench's file import wizard before.

Comment: Mike, see the screenshot I posted in the OP. Any idea why it won't recognize my USE database command? I have created a database and selected it. Then I used the file import wizard but the error in the screenshot comes up. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one table and use a primary key with no business value, e.g.

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

in your create table statement.

You'd end up with data similar to:

```
id  file_id descrip Date       file_heat_value_1 
1   1       ABC     2015-02-11     1.02500 
2   1       ABC     2014-11-19     0.85500 
3   1       ABC     2014-05-22    17.20 
4   2       DEF     2014-08-20     1.3700 
5   2       DEF     2014-05-21    15.5500 
6   2       DEF     2013-04-07    77.800 
7   3       XYZ     2012-02-12     0.14400 
8   3       XYZ     2013-02-12     0.97600
9   1       ABC     2014-12-01    42.01 
10  1       ABC     2013-04-02 11389.90
11  2       DEF     2014-12-03     0.87
12  2       DEF     2014-12-04    55.36
13  2       DEF     2014-07-04   143.29
14  3       XYZ     2012-11-05 77.90.02
15  3       XYZ     2013-07-08 34344.91
```

You can then select the data form this one table.  Post another question if you need help with the select statement for that.

Comment: Thanks. That does it. I actually just have 2 questions: A. is it typical to use a dummy PK column> i.e. to use a PK that has no real meaning? B. I am leaning towards using 2 tables - each with a dummy PK column, that way I get to keep `file_heat_value_1` and `file_heat_value_2`. I then perform an `inner join` on `file_id` column which is the same for both tables. Any thoughts on this compared to your suggestion of combining everything into one table?

Comment: Using a dummy primary key is not only typical, it's considered a best practice by many.  You'll find it much easier to avoid or detect dupes and other issues.  More on this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key/218365#218365

Comment: Some other approaches with the one table approach: use group by, possibly group_by file_id, or add another column called csv_source that has a 1 or 2 depending on which csv was the source and group by that, or order by file_id and add TOP 1 for max values, or combine group and order with LIMIT.  The options are many.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My questions here have been answered.